# how to get individual songs from wordpress audio playlist?

Tags: php, wordpress, audio, playlist

I am trying to get songs name and url from a playlist that is created. Playlist is generated dynamically when a post is created. I will have to loop through those posts and get playlist which I want to split and display name, duration etc.

I have searched but all I can find is plugins for those playlists.

I want to split the audio files form the playlist of post and display only names of the songs in some part of my website.

I can display single audio file as

```
$music_file = get_template_directory_uri() . "/sounds/music.mp3"; 
echo do_shortcode('[audio mp3=' . $music_file . ']');
```

but I want to get all the audio files from playlist and loop through them individually and create a custom display of the playlist.

**Update**

For example I can get individual images from gallery by using `$gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post )`. Is there a function that can do the same for audio playlist.

Playlist is created from media upload in editor

[image]

Comment: `from playlist` where is this playlist defined? In your current example, you are fetching an individual file from disk by name. How is the _playlist_ stored? You will need to fetch the playlist, then loop each line loading the files. The actual impl we can not produce until we know what the playlist actually is.

Comment: playlist can be created from media upload section. hold on I will explain further

Comment: Ah, my mistake then, I was unaware WordPress added this feature. Is this by default? Or are you using a plugin? Maybe try asking at [Wordpress SE](https://WordPress.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Here's a [wpse_get_post_playlists()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/273994/26350) example.

Answer (score 2):

Though your question isn't really clear, but this code will help you find each audio name/url in your playlist:

```
// your playlist shortcode
$playlist_shortcode = '[playlist ids="2217,2578,2579"]';

// Find registered tag names in your $playlist_shortcode.
preg_match('/' . get_shortcode_regex() . '/', $playlist_shortcode, $match );

// Parse playlist shortcode attributes
$playlist_attr = shortcode_parse_atts($match[3]);

// Retrieve audio ids
$audio_id = explode(',',$playlist_attr['ids']);
foreach($audio_id as $id ){
    // Single audio title
    echo get_the_title($id);

    echo do_shortcode('[audio mp3=' . wp_get_attachment_url($id) . ']');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the source code for [`wp_playlist_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_playlist_shortcode/) you will find the query that's needed, which can be extracted and used to build a query of your own, as follows.

```
<?php
$playlist_attachments = get_children( [
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),

    'post_type'      => 'attachment', // Attachment post type.
    'post_mime_type' => 'audio', // Audio file attachments.
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order ID', // Playlist order.
    'order'          => 'ASC', // Ascending order.
] );

foreach ( $playlist_attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_link( $id ) . "\n";
}
```

With that, you have the attachment ID and object for each of the audio files in the playlist. So you can get more creative if you'd like, and instead of calling [`wp_get_attachment_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_link/), consider using [`wp_get_attachment_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/). You may also find it helpful to review the source of [`wp_playlist_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_playlist_shortcode/) and extract more, so you can tune things in just the way you'd like.

Comment: thank you for the reply but `$playlist_attachments` returns empty array, I also tried and changed the parameters but still result is empty set of array

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through all the `post_type` *attachments*, where `post_mime_type` is *audio*.

See the WordPress documentation page for [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to see what options you can pass to the `get_posts()` function.

```
// Specify options here
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'audio',
    'numberposts' => -1
);

// This is now an array with all audio files
$audiofiles = get_posts($args);

foreach ($audiofiles as $file)
{   
     // Do what ever you want with it here ...
     // Eg.
     $url = wp_get_attachment_url($file->ID);
     echo $url; // url
     echo file->post_title; //title
     echo file->post_content; // description
}
```

If you only want to retrieve the *audio* files based on the current post. Then add the `post_parent` to the `$args` array. Eg.

```
'post_parent' => $post->ID // Which is the current post ID
```